# setting a php var to * (all)

Tags: php, zip

Im using the bellow code to create and download a zip file from all the files in the root of the folder. 
Ive got this line

```
$files_to_zip = array(
      'room1.jpg', 'room2.jpg'
    );
```

which lets you chose which files to put into the zip file - but my files are the result of a cron job so theres a new one generated each day. How can i write a variable to say all files, apart from " " and then list the files that i dont want in the zipfolder ie. index.php ect..

so far ive tried writing `$files_to_zip = *;` (obviously that would not exclude any files) but that just throws up a **Parse error: syntax error**

this is the full code bellow:

```
 <?php
    /* creates a compressed zip file */
    function create_zip($files = array(),$destination = '',$overwrite = true) {
      //if the zip file already exists and overwrite is false, return false
      if(file_exists($destination) && !$overwrite) { return false; }
      //vars
      $valid_files = array();
      //if files were passed in...
      if(is_array($files)) {
        //cycle through each file
        foreach($files as $file) {
          //make sure the file exists
          if(file_exists($file)) {
            $valid_files[] = $file;
          }
        }
      }
      //if we have good files...
      if(count($valid_files)) {
        //create the archive
        $zip = new ZipArchive();
        if($zip->open($destination,$overwrite ? ZIPARCHIVE::OVERWRITE : ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE) !== true) {
          return false;
        }
        //add the files
        foreach($valid_files as $file) {
          $zip->addFile($file,$file);
        }
        //debug
        //echo 'The zip archive contains ',$zip->numFiles,' files with a status of ',$zip->status;

        //close the zip -- done!
        $zip->close();

        //check to make sure the file exists
        return file_exists($destination);
      }
      else
      {
        return false;
      }
    }



    $files_to_zip = array(
      'room1.jpg', 'room2.jpg'
    );
    //if true, good; if false, zip creation failed
    $zip_name = 'my-archive.zip';
    $result = create_zip($files_to_zip,$zip_name);

    if($result){
    header('Content-Type: application/zip');
    header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=filename.zip');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($zip_name));
    readfile($zip_name);
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Isn't this just the `glob()` function?

Comment: @Barmar You should probably post an answer explaining `glob()`. ;)

Comment: yes thanks @barmar that worked great.. sorry im still getting the hang of php.. but thanks for pointing me in the right direction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function to do wildcard matching against the filesystem is `glob()`.

```
$files_to_zip = glob("*");
```